# Rails seed file exits loop creating less than the specified users

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, seed

I have a seed file in a rails 3.2.2 app that creates users for me to test the site layout and forms with. It should generate a single admin and 10 users, but it only creates the admin and 2 users without any explaination for why it stops. It does not throw and exception and everything looks fine until I check the database.

here is the code

```
require 'faker'

# Create an Admin user to test the site with
Admin.create first_name: "Admin",
         last_name: "User",
         email: "admin.user@example.com",
         password: "foobarbaz",
         password_confirmation: "foobarbaz"

# Generate 10 users to test with
10.times do
  student_address = { street: Faker::Address.street_address,
                  city: Faker::Address.city,
                  state: Faker::Address.us_state_abbr,
                  zipcode: Faker::Address.zip_code }
  first_name = Faker::Name.first_name
  last_name = Faker::Name.last_name

  Student.create first_name: first_name,
             last_name: last_name,
             email: "#{first_name}.#{last_name}@example.com",
             student_id: rand(10 ** 6).to_s.rjust(6,'0'),
             address_attributes: student_address,
             phone_number: Faker::PhoneNumber.phone_number,
             password: "foobar",
             password_confirmation: "foobar"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the create or update_attributes to raise an exception for invalid records, you need to use the corresponding "bang" versions.

```
Student.create!
```

Comment: Thanks, the create "bang" helped me pinpoint the problem. Faker generates the zipcode and phone numbers differently for each new user and they sometimes have an extra number or the longer version of a zip code. I changed it to take out all the non-integer characters and only select the first 5 or 10 digits with a range.

Comment: Thanks for describing the exact problem. It will help future viewers.